# Online math question didn't do a square of a square root properly?

Tags: rational-numbers

I'm currently taking an online college math course, and I recently came across something that I can't make any sense out of.

> $(\frac{5x \cdot \sqrt{3}}{6})^2 = \frac{25x^2}{12}$

It looks like the problem is just completely throwing away the $\sqrt{3}$ instead of doing $25x \cdot 3$. Is there some condition where squaring a square root in the numerator of a fraction just gets rid of it or something? Or is it possible that this is an error with the site?

Comment: But $6^2 = 36$. The $3$ is cancelled, $\frac{3}{36} = \frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: You should be hearing the resounding boom of my facepalm soon.

Answer (score 1):

$(\frac{5x \sqrt{3}}{6})^{2}=\frac{25x^{2}\times 3}{36}$